# My viewcontroller (in the navcontroller) I load in my app delegate overlaps the tabbar

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having trouble initializing a viewcontroller when the app loads in my app delegate.  The viewcontroller loads okay, but it overlaps the tabbar that I have at the bottom.  Do I need to create another viewcontroller and have it load into that in the app delegate?  I currently have a tabBarController set up in my MainWindow.xib, which contains Navigation controllers and inside those are viewControllers.

Here is my code...

In my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I have:

```
sub = [[SubGabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubGabViewController" bundle:nil];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sub];
[window addSubview:nav.view];
```

Should it be something like?

```
sub = [[SubGabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubGabViewController" bundle:nil];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sub];
[newViewController.view addSubview:nav.view];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use a UITabBarController, each tab has its own root view controller (these can even be UINavigationController objects).  Assuming you have a property for self.tabBarController (I think this gets created by default in Xcode if you are doing a tab-bar app), then:

```
sub = [[SubGabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubGabViewContrller" bundle:nil];
nav = [[UINavigationContoller alloc] initWithRootViewController:sub];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nav] animated:NO];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
// Clean up memory here... only if you don't need references to them
[sub release];
[nav release];
```

With setViewControllers:animated: you should probably include additional view controllers in the NSArray, otherwise you'll end up with a tab bar only containing one item!

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close!  But instead of creating a new tabbar, can I just add to the one I already created in interface builder?  By linking it up with IBOutlets?

Answer (score 0):

`[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];` would be right......

Rather than adding navigation controller using code..... you should add it from Interface Builder.... in interface builder remove the `tabBarItem` and add a `navigationController` on it and then set `viewController` for that navigation controller..........

create an outlet of `tabBarController` in `appDelegate` so that you can add it on `window`. Pleas do not forget to make connection between components in Interface Builder.

Thanks,